# PHP Gives Infinite While Loop when mysqli_fetch_assoc Expression is Replaced with just a Variable

Tags: php, while-loop, mysqli

I'm a complete newbie in PHP and I just don't understand how `while` loop works with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. The former execute statements based upon expressions, the latter retrieves a row from the database. So if you don't end the loop, it will continue to iterate the field in the first row infinitely;

```
<?php
$connect_db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','db');
$fetch_data="SELECT * FROM tabel";
$query_db=mysqli_query($connect_db,$fetch_data);
$fetch_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_db);
while($fetch_row){
    $column_2_array=$fetch_row['column_2'];
    echo($column_2_array);
    break;
}
?>
```

What I'm scratching my head is if the whole expression is put inside the parentheses instead of just the variable, then the loop will iterates the whole content of the column.

```
<?php
$connect_db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','db');
$fetch_data="SELECT * FROM tabel";
$query_db=mysqli_query($connect_db,$fetch_data);
while($fetch_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_db)){
    $column_2_array=$fetch_row['column_2'];
    echo($column_2_array);
}
?>
```

Why is it that on the second example above, after the first loop, `while` is iterating the subsequent rows on the selected column?

Clarifying my question further, if I take away `break` from the first example, then what is the difference between example 1 and 2? This is what confuses me since I thought they're identical.

Comment: In PHP, nonempty arrays evaluate to true

Comment: Why you are using loop to display single row. If you want to display multiple rows then use `mysqli_fetch_array()` within loop

Comment: I need to understand why on the second example, the loop displays all rows on the selected column instead of only the first row as per the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why this approach of looping mysqli_result works with a `while` loop you need to understand two things:

- PHP uses [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). Each row returned by `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` will be an array. It is safe to assume that this array will never be empty, so the value will always be cast to `true` when used in boolean context.
- `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns a single row from the result and moves an internal pointer to the next row. When pointer reaches the last row, each subsequent call will return `NULL`.

This while loop is equivalent to:

```
$fetch_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_db); // save the first row in the variable. It could also be false
while($fetch_row) { // as long as $fetch_row is not false-ish
    $column_2_array = $fetch_row['column_2'];
    echo $column_2_array;

    // fetch false or the next row
    $fetch_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_db)
}
```

Worth noting that such an approach to looping is not recommended. It is much easier to use a `foreach` loop. This will loop on the whole resultset one by one from the first row until the last. You can loop the same `mysqli_result` object multiple times.

```
foreach($query_db as $fetch_row) {
    $column_2_array = $fetch_row['column_2'];
    echo $column_2_array;
}
```

An even better alternative is to use `fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` and store all rows in a multi-dimensional array. And as always, use PDO instead of mysqli whenever possible.

Comment: That's really helpful! I thought in the tutorial (from which this example came from) why wasn't foreach used but I don't know how to do it until you showed it to me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest explanation is,

When you run [`mysqli_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object which contains data from the database.

---

- [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) - Fetch a result row(one row from the `mysqli_result` object) as an associative array at each time it called and moves the internal pointer to the next. `$fetch_row` is used to store that associative array containing **data of single row getting from the `mysqli_result` object**'

you can retrieve data belongs to that raw by using `$fetch_row['column_name']`

- The `while` loop does the calling of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` over and over. After one row is fetched, it goes to the next one and so on till it reaches the end of the object and returns `NULL`, which means `false` and `breaks` the `while` loop.

---

So in your first code sample,

`$fetch_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_db);`  will return and assign only one data row to `$fetch_row` (data type- assoc. array). Which makes the condition of the `while` loop `true`.

Comment: What I don't understand is why does the `while` loop moves to the next rows on the second example? What is the difference between the first and the second examples?

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify my question further. If I take away `break` from the first example, then what is the difference between example 1 and 2? This is what confuses me since I thought they're identical.

Comment: The first code will not get all the data in the table. Because `$fetch_row` has only one raw(first raw in table) assign to it and not iterating through rows. Array is not empty, represents `true` state. But in second code it will iterate and assign each row in the table to the `$fetch_row` variable .

Comment: I think I get it now. `mysqli_fetch_assoc` pulls a single row as an expression or iterates the whole rows as condition in a loop.

Comment: @user3134685 Provided Example in the answer is just an explanation. That is NOT THE WAY IT ACTUALLY works.

Comment: @user3134685, I've edited the answer, please refer hat is what actually happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212610/discussion-between-user3134685-and-avishka-dambawinna).